# Remove field from a nested array in collection in MongoDb using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to remove nested fields (`id` and `type`) in `batter` array in the collection. The matching condition being where `batter.id="1001"`. Images of collections are attached before and after update.

I have tried the below code:

```python
def remove_field(database_name, collection_name):
    collection = database_name[collection_name]
    match_criteria = ["batter": {$elemMatch" : {"id":"1001"}}]
    result = collection.update_many(match_criteria, {"$unset: {"batter.$.id":1,"data.$.type":1 }})
```

This code only deletes the `batter.id` field where the value is `1001`, and it does not remove `type` field.

Please find attached image of document I am trying to update: [collection_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atlPO.png) and the output I am getting [collection_result_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwQkj.png)

Comment: have you tried $pull as well?

Comment: yes, but that's used for values.

Comment: @Krypto456 is on the right track.  Try with [`{"$pull": {"batter": {"id": "1001"}}}`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A5UMJjWhqTM).